# ¿Como mantener un checkbox seleccionado con Jquery?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Tengo una tabla que se llena con un while y en ella tengo unos input tipo Checkbox que selecciono, hasta aqui todo normal, pero al momento de usar un input como buscador, la tabla me muestra los valores del buscar en la tabla, pero al momento de borrar el valor que hay en el input la tabla vuelve a como se cargo originalmente con los check desmarcados.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $output .= '
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="'.$row["ID_EMPLEADO"].'" name="first_id_empleado[]" class="empleado" id="first_id_empleado'.$row["ID_EMPLEADO"].'" "/></td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EMP_NOMBRES"]).'</td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EMP_APELLIDO1"]).'</td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EMP_APELLIDO2"]).'</td>
    <td>'.$row["EMP_CEDULA"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["EMP_FEC_INGRESO"].'</td>
    </tr>';
```

No se como hacer para que el check se mantenga seleccionado al momento de utilizar el buscador

Comment: El codigo tal cual esta presentado no parece sintácticamente correcto, puedes compartir la parte del codigo completa (con inicio/fin de comillas)?

Comment: Es un while que recorre una sentencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que estas recibiendo la misma informacion del formulario, puedes checkear si el valor esta presente en lo enviado anteriormente (Aqui uso `$_REQUEST` que es generico, pero podrias usar `$_GET` o `$_POST` segun el metodo de envio del form):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $checked=in_array($row["ID_EMPLEADO"],$_REQUEST['first_id_empleado']?'checked':'';
    $output .= '
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" 
     value="'.$row["ID_EMPLEADO"].'" name="first_id_empleado[]" 
     class="empleado" '.$checked.' id="first_id_empleado'.$row["ID_EMPLEADO"].'" "/></td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EMP_NOMBRES"]).'</td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EMP_APELLIDO1"]).'</td>
    <td>'.utf8_encode($row["EMP_APELLIDO2"]).'</td>
    <td>'.$row["EMP_CEDULA"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["EMP_FEC_INGRESO"].'</td>
    </tr>';
```

Explicacion: si el input usa el nombre `first_id_empleado[]`, los valores (`value`) previamente chequeados aparecen en el array resultante (`$_REQUEST['first_id_empleado']`). Si el valor actual (`$row["ID_EMPLEADO"]`) esta incluido en dicho array, se marca como seleccionado (`checked`).

Answer (score 0):

El input para que quede seleccionado debe llevar checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name1" value="valor" checked>
```